# Gracefully terminate Rails Application from within

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I have a Rails 5 application (API) and a postgres DB that run on separate docker containers, all on the same AWS EC2 instance, and are controlled by an external manager (manage).  *manage* needs to be able to make a request to the *API* and tell it to exit.  I don't want to just kill the API externally or the docker container, as I want all *API* requests to complete.  I want the *API* to exit gracefully and only it knows how to do that.
Ruby has exit, exit! and abort.  All of them seem to be handled by Rails as exceptions and Rails just continues motoring on.

How can I terminate my rails application from within?  Is there some sort of unhandleable exception that I can raise?

Comment: You could also tell a rails app server (puma or what-have-you?) to gracefully shutdown. I am quite sure that most/all servers will do just that in response to a SIGTERM.

Comment: The problem with "make it stop by hitting an api endpoint" is: what happens when you add another api container? Or 10, or 500? Api request can hit only one of them and, depending on your routing logic, it'll likely be a random one. While you theoretically could terminate this server instance, the others will continue untouched.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Right now the application has no need to scale that way.  Should things change, we would address it with a different mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the ApplicationController is rescuing the SystemExit. Looking at the Rails source, there is a `rescue Exception` in ActionController, which includes ActiveSupport::Rescuable. That's where the controller methods like `rescue_from` are defined.

I tested this in a controller in a Rails API app, sent it a request, and Rails did indeed exit immediately, with an empty response to the caller:

> ```
> class ProcessesController < ApplicationController
>   rescue_from SystemExit, with: :my_exit
>
>   def destroy
>     CleanupClass.method_that_exits
>     render json: { status: :ok }
>   end
>
>   def my_exit
>     exit!
>   end
> end
>
> class CleanupClass
>   def self.method_that_exits
>     exit
>   end
> end
> ```